# Getting error connectring to Hive.Error:java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2:

Tags: node.js, express, jdbc, hive

Hi I am trying to connect to hive from Nodejs. I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc to install JDBC. I get the following error:

> Error: Error running static method java.sql.SQLException: No suitable
>   driver found for jdbc:hive2:

Here is my code:

```
var JDBC = require('jdbc');
var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');

if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
  jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
  jinst.setupClasspath(['./drivers/hsqldb.jar',
                    './drivers/derby.jar',
                    './drivers/derbyclient.jar',
                    './drivers/derbytools.jar']);
}

 var jdbcconfig = {
 url: 'jdbc:hive2://hdprd1-edge-lb01:20000',
 user : 'user',
 password: 'password'
};
```

I am not sure which driver to mention, I know there is a config property called `drivername` but not sure which driver to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to connect to a hive database, why are you loading the HSQLDB jars (or vice versa, why are you using a hive2 URL if you want to connecto to a HSQLDB)? Please specify the type of database your connecting to.

Comment: Did you try to search for Hive JDBC client?
 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC

Comment: Hi Mark Rotteveel, I am connecting to Hive2 database, I am new to node and i used example here https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc.Could you please help me with this