# Need an example to connect to hive db from node js

Tags: node.js, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to connect to hive db form Node js, I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc .I also tried using this driver 
    drivername: `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`

I am getting below error:

> Error: Error running static method java.sql.SQLException: No suitable
>   driver found for jdbc:hive2://hdprd1-edge-lb01:20000
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)

Here is my code snippet

```
    var JDBC = require('jdbc');
    var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');

    if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
      // Add all java options required by your project here.  You get one chance to
      // setup the options before the first java call.
      jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
      // Add all jar files required by your project here.  You get one chance to
      // setup the classpath before the first java call.
      jinst.setupClasspath(['./drivers/derby.jar',
                            './drivers/derbyclient.jar',
                            './drivers/derbytools.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/hive-exec-1.2.1.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/hive-common-1.2.1.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/hive-service-1.2.1.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/httpclient-4.3.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/httpcore-4.3.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/libthrift-0.9.1.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/libfb303-0.9.0.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/org-apache-commons-logging.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/hive-exec*.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/antlr-runtime-3.0.1.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/derby.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/jdo2-api-2.1.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/jpox-core-1.2.2.jar',
                            './lib/drivers/jpox-rdbms-1.2.2.jar'
                            ]);
    }



    var jdbcconfig = {
      url: 'jdbc:hive2://hdprd1-edge-lb01:20000',
      user : 'user',
      password: 'password'
    };

    var testpool = null;
    var testconn = null;
    var hsqldb = new JDBC(jdbcconfig);

    hsqldb.initialize(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please do not repost.  [Getting error connectring to Hive.Error:java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive2:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837111/getting-error-connectring-to-hive-errorjava-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-drive)

Comment: You need the **standalone** JAR. http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/1.2.1/ Not exec,common,metastore,service,etc.

Comment: @cricket_007 , i downloaded standalone jar and included as shown below  jinst.setupClasspath(['./drivers/hive-jdbc-1.2.1-standalone.jar']);, still getting same error

Comment: Are you sure `jinst.isJvmCreated` is returning false?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't rely on using Java or JDBC. Hive supports Thrift. For example https://github.com/imjuni/jshs2

Comment: Yes i commented if loop having that condition, still getting sam error, i cannot use jshs2 only supports Nosasl, and we require to use authentication in our project